# find count from different collection in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, query-optimization

I have multiple collections, and I want to get the count of each collection from Mongo, as of now what I did is, I created an individual query to get the count from each collection,
here below is the example

```
  const aCount = await this.aModal.count();
  const bCount = await this.bModal.count();
  const cCount = await this.cModal.count();
  const dCount = await this.dModal.count();
  const eCount = await this.eModel.count();
  const fCount= await this.fModal.count();
  const gCount= await this.gModal.count();
```

here, I'm doing several DB calls, Are there any other ways to avoid multiple DB calls?
any help or suggestions are really helpful

**Note:**

I'm using NestJs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb) as a Framework with `mongoose`